# Scheduling task on remote using cmdline schtasks.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been having issue with scheduling task on remote machine. Here's 2 sample of what I've been experiencing

I scheduled a task on a remote machine using the ff cmd line:

> schtasks /create /s targetmachine /tn "Test Task" /tr notepad.exe /sc hourly /rl highest

1st sample:
i got 2 machines, 1  to send the cmd line from and 1 as target machine. on both machine i used the same account to log in(user1). I sent the cmd line, the task got created and was able to run on the target machine.

2nd sample:
i got another machine and had a different account logged in(user2). i sent the cmd line and the task got created but the task didn't run

what i've done to isolate the issue:
-i've used different cmd line like:

> schtasks /create /s targetmachine /u user1 /p user1pw /tn "Test Task" /tr notepad.exe /sc hourly /rl highest
>
> schtasks /create /s targetmachine /np /ru system /tn "Test Task" /tr notepad.exe /sc hourly /rl highest
>
> schtasks /create /s targetmachine /ru user1 /rp user1pw /tn "Test Task" /tr notepad.exe /sc hourly /rl highest

-on the user2 machine, i opened the task scheduler and click on "changed user or group" under the general tab. i set the task to use the user2 account. after manually initiating the task i was able to run it.

Any ideas on what i can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

After further research i have concluded that it is impossible to run a task under your own account on another machine with a different user logged in. the use of /ru, /rp, /u /p or SYSTEM and NT Authority\System and /np doesn't help either, it creates the task but doesn't get it to run i have tested this multiple times and the same keeps happening. as a workaround i have decided to get the currently logged in user account thru powershell and use that account instead.